# What is the minimum-volume : neutral-volume : maximum-volume of the molecules that make up the SARS-Cov-2 virus-fusion machine?

Tags: molecular-biology, mutations, cell-cycle, host-pathogen-interaction, symmetry

The "neutral-volume" is the over-lapping volume between minimum-volume & maximum-volume of the molecules that make up the SARS-Cov-2-fusion machine. Those identifying potential differences that support particle-flow inside the SARS-Cov-2-fusion machine-molecule have certain degree's of freedom. The best description of the structural dynamics of the Sars-COV-2-fusion machine that I have found was in "Scientific American", July-2020-issue/page 34,.
A base understanding of the "open-loop & closed-looped" particle-flow-symmetry is needed to explain the action of why the fusion machine of the SARS-Cov-2 virus binds to a lung-cell. The way I understand it, there is an exchange of particle-mass, starting with disorganizing lung-cell-mass by this virus at point of attachment, then re-organization occurs between the lung-cell and the SARS-Cov-2-fusion machines particle-flow grid. The SARS-Cov-2-fusion-machine may in fact accelerate into the lung cell, (to-push & bend/in the act of causing mass to dis-organize) and then deaccelerates, causing the act of organizing particle-flow between the two cells (to pull-straight/in the act of synchronizing & organizing), producing a certain closed-looped function between the virus-cell & the lung-cell. What are those unseen differentials between what is seen and what is not seen? Covalent bonding is straight-forward and well understood, except for the fact that there are other molecular actions involved. Would this be a function of two under-square vortexes, Van Der Wall-forces, Brownian motion, the action of dipoles, or something else? ALL of which may in fact contribute to an exchange of mass of which brings on those pulling forces that bind. There is a certain working-mass having a certain energy efficiency per location per time that changes the squareness of the SARS-Cov-2-fusion machine. Volume displacement of heavenly bodies plays a critical roll as to the way particles move around and through them, i.e. outer-space becoming inner-space & inner-space becoming outer-space per location per time.

Comment: I appreciate that scientists from different disciplines view problems from different perspectives, but perhaps you should consider that too if you post on lists frequented by biologists who clearly have a different perspective from you. Your concerns are not their concerns, and I cannot imagine that you will receive an intelligent answer here.  The fact that you include totally irrelevant tags such as “mutation” and “cell cycle” signals that you have come to the wrong address.

Comment: Thank you David your input is greatly appreciated and I thank biology-stack exchange for giving me the opportunity to post. I made a mistake in that I should have used the "dissociation constant" in my descriptive terminology, for I am bound to the capitalism beast and I an limited as to what I can post.